# Trying to retrieve a record with get :index, based on user, nothing getting returned. Response OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, rspec, devise, controller

I'm trying to retrieve a record based on a user id. To make sure that my get controller's index works appropriately. Here is my controller snippet.

```
class SimulationsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        if current_user 
            @simulations = current_user.simulations
        else 
            redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
        end
    end
```

Now I put some traces in my below controller spec. From what I'm gatherin from these traces there are four Simulations that exist for the test with the User_ID 1, however the User thats being created for the test, and the records along with it in the test are all User_ID 5. Can anyone give some guidance I'm pretty stumped beating my head on this. Additionally I'm getting a Response: OK. EDIT: Updated Spec with below answer.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SimulationsController, :type => :controller do

    let :user do 
        FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    before(:each) do
        puts "~#{user.id}"
        sign_in user    
    end

    describe "GET #index" do 

        it "returns the correct number of simulations" do 
            simulation = FactoryGirl.build(:simulation, user: user)
            simulation.save!
            puts "@@@@#{simulation.user_id}"

            puts user.id
            Simulation.all.each do |sim| 
                puts sim.user_id
            end

            get :index
            puts "---\t\t#{response.body.size}"
            # expect(response).to be_success            
        end

    end

end
```

EDIT 2:

User Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        email "user_#{User.last.nil? ? 1 : User.last.id + 1}@home.com"
        password "password"
    end
end
```

Simulation Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :simulation do |f|
        f.id (Simulation.last.nil? ? 1 : Simulation.last.id + 1)
        f.x_size 3
        f.y_size 3
        f.user_id 1
    end 
end
```

Final Edit: I was going about checking wrong, as outlined below, Body isn't what I was looking for I wanted to use assigns as I did below to check what I wanted too:

```
    it "returns the correct number of simulations" do 
        simulation = FactoryGirl.build(:simulation, user: user)
        simulation.save!

        get :index

        expect(assigns(:simulations).size).to eq 1
    end
```

Comment: In what way does the result of running your spec differ from your expectations?

Comment: response.body.size is returning zero and I'm expecting it to return 1, for the one record that belongs to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.body` is the rendered HTML, so its size would be length of that string. Depending on what your view looks like there might not be a straightforward correlation between its size and the number of simulations rendered.

In addition by default rspec doesn't render views at all in controller specs and so `response.body` will always be an empty string. You can change this by adding `render_views` to the example group.

Comment: So I should just trust that if my response is 200, the correct records are being returned?

Comment: You can also use `assigns` to read controller instance variables. In an integration spec you can check the structure / content of the HTML too

Comment: Yep Assigns totally works.. I spent way longer on this then I needed to I passed by that hours ago.. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Probably FactoryGirl overrides your user_id assignment, because you have `association :user` being set up there. Just change `user_id` to `user` and it should work:

```
simulation = FactoryGirl.build(:simulation, user: user)
```

**UPD**. And fix your factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :simulation do |f|
        # Never set ID manually
        # f.id (Simulation.last.nil? ? 1 : Simulation.last.id + 1)
        f.x_size 3
        f.y_size 3
        # f.user_id 1
        # user 'association' method to set up associations
        f.association :user
    end 
end
```

**UPD2**. To check if you controller assigned variable properly, use `assigns`:

```
expect(assigns(:simulations).length).to eq 4
```

You almost never should compare your `response.body` to anything – because, well, it's just raw body. To test your views you use special expectation methods, and to check instance `@`-variables assignments you use `assigns`.

Comment: I'm still getting the same results from my traces and no records returned, I updated my SPEC code above, any other ideas @EugZol

Comment: Well, now that's strange. Please add factories.rb to your answer.

Comment: I mean, am I querying the index right as well? Do I need to give it a User_ID at all? Or do I not like I have it above.. and Why cant I find any other examples of people actually checking the correct number of records are returned online, it looks like most people just test for a response okay.

Comment: I guess I was going about asking wrong, thanks for your help though!

Comment: Man, you totally confuse things :) Now you accept an answer of another user, and then you update your question with a remark that you actually needed information from my answer :) So now instead of only you being confused with something you have at least two other people as well, like some kind of droplet infection :)

Comment: I just updated my solution so it was clear what the solution was, you both gave me a correct answer Frederick sent first which is why I marked it, is the a better way of clearing this up?